# Setting up relationship between Users table and other tables like Clients in a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core, but this is more of a database schema question. I know how to set up relationships, but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

I have a table called 'AppUsers' which I'm using primarily for identity authentication purposes. So all app users will have a record in that table. I also have the following tables: Designers, Clients, and Workrooms. All designers, clients, and workrooms are app users and should have a record in AppUsers. I initially set up one-to-one relationships between AppUsers and Designers, AppUsers and Clients, etc.

The problem with that is I also need many-to-many relationships between Designers and Clients and Designers and Workrooms. This throws an error: 'may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.' I could probably define the cascade behavior and get around this, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

This is my AppUsers model minus irrelevant properties:

```
public class AppUserModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public int? DesignerId { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }

        public int? WorkroomId { get; set; }  

        ...
    }
```

I no longer have one-to-one relations, instead, I simply have nullable int properties for Ids for designers, clients, and workrooms. So I would check for null on these properties and then get a designer record, for example, by the Id. So now there is no relationship between these tables.

I still have the many-to-many relationships between Designers and Clients and Designers and WorkRooms. This is necessary because clients and workrooms can have multiple designers.

This will work, I suppose, but I'm no database expert and I don't know if there is a better way to handle this. I would appreciate any guidance.

Are one-to-one relations necessary for AppUser and Designers etc. tables? Or would the nullable ints be good enough?

Comment: You need to be more descriptive: what is the many-tom-many relationship between those three supposed to represent?

Comment: I edited the post. The many-to-many relationships are needed because clients and workrooms can work with multiple designers.

Comment: You already checked out the Table per Hierarchy approach? With this approach you could save all designers, clients, workrooms in one table differentiated by a discriminator. Its implemented via a common base type. Then you could let the base type `AppUserModel` have a many to many relationship between themself and other AppUsers. The many to many relationship will be solved by entity framework core itself and will lead to a new pivot table. May the name be AppUserAppUsers because its a relation upon itself.

Comment: I chose another approach in the beginnings of 2.0 and 3.1. I created a table which would be called in your situation ClientWorkroomDesigners. Regarding your three different types you would need an enum to differentiate between your types. In addition i created a ClientInfo, WorkroomInfo, DesignerInfo tables for additional information and made a one to one relationship between those AppUsers. The problem was that there are 2 of 3 navigation properties null. Despite that I created a relationship table which allowed me to create relations between those ClientWorkroomDesigners

Comment: Thanks.  I was just wondering if a table can have many-to-many with itself. I will give the Table per Hierarchy approach a try.

Comment: You do not need many to many.  You may want to do a query and get many, but the relationship in the database is one to one.

Comment: @DavidEvans it definitely can have a many to many relation on itself. I don't know if NET 5 EF recognizes the relationship. If it doesnt, you need to set it up yourself with an own created entity, own `EntityTypeConfiguration` and own set relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following:

- All Designers and Clients are AppUsers.
- A Designer and Client can be associated with a Workroom.
- Any Designer can be associated with any Client

Something like this may do:

[image]

If there is a one to one relationship between an AppUser and a Designer, Client or Workroom record then we would change the relationships to:

[image]

This ensures that each Designer, Client and Workroom record has an assigned,  AppUser record, whilst allowing any mix of Designer, Client and Workroom records (assumption is that every Designer works with a Client and in a Workroom).

The `WorkroomUsage` relationship table allows us to have multiple relationships between Clients, Designers and Workrooms just by having more records.

For example:
2 Designers (ids #1 & #2), 1 Client (id #1), 1 Workroom (id #1) would be:

Designer #1, Client #1, Workroom #1

Designer #2, Client #1, Workroom #1

Comment: OC wrote that workrooms are also app users `All designers, clients, and workrooms are app users and should have a record in AppUsers.` And i might understand there is a relationship between designers and clients. And also a relationship between designers and workrooms. Because i guess the designer can choose from different workrooms and the clients are not bound to the workrooms. Its like the teacher is saying `today we are in this room`. The clients are following the designer and not the room. Am i right?

Comment: If a Designer and Client must use a Workroom, then the `WorkroomUsage` relationship table stands. If the Workroom is optional then you would need a separate table to cover that relationship. Personally, I don't think that a Workroom should have an AppUser relationship if its not an application Actor, but just a resource.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant was "If the Workroom is optional then you would need either a separate table to cover that relationship or allow `workroomId` to be `null` in the table.

Comment: Thanks. This is all very helpful. I set up table-per-hierarchy pattern per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance  Yes workrooms are app users because they will sign in the app and get design specs sent from designers. So designers need many-to-many with workrooms and clients.